# A simple synonym matcher in Prolog (well, rubylog)

Tags: ruby, prolog

I'm experimenting with rubylog, which is a Prolog for Ruby. My goal is to create logical links between words to dig up connections between documents I may not otherwise notice. I've only started today, and I'm playing with a synonym detector. Oddly, it seems like I've made the synonym rules almost-but-not-quite symmetric and transitive.

In this example, I'm trying to teach Prolog that 'math', 'maths', and 'mathematics' are all synonyms:

```
require 'rubylog'
include Rubylog::DSL::Constants

Symbol.rubylog_functor :synonym
Symbol.rubylog_functor :synonym_of
X.synonym(Y).if X.synonym_of(Y)
X.synonym(Y).if Y.synonym_of(X)
X.synonym(Z).if X.synonym_of(Y).and Y.synonym_of(Z)   ###########

:math.synonym_of! :mathematics
:mathematics.synonym_of! :maths
puts "Synonyms for math: #{:math.synonym(X).to_a}"
puts "Synonyms for maths: #{:maths.synonym(X).to_a}"
puts "Synonyms for mathematics: #{:mathematics.synonym(X).to_a}"
```

To my surprise, the result is

```
Synonyms for math: [:mathematics, :maths]
Synonyms for maths: [:mathematics]
Synonyms for mathematics: [:maths, :math]
```

I thought that the problem might be that the line marked `###########` uses `synonym_of` instead of `synonym`, and so perhaps the rule was not being described recursively. But changing that line to `X.synonym(Z).if X.synonym_of(Y).and Y.synonym(Z)` gives the very strange output

```
Synonyms for math: [:mathematics, :maths, :math, :mathematics]
Synonyms for maths: [:mathematics]
Synonyms for mathematics: [:maths, :math, :mathematics]
```

Very curious! What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after modelling a transitive closure on a directed graph, and then you should use a recursive rule for the transitive property, but guarding against loops.

The practical way I can suggest is to write *explicitly* a rule for synonyms (sorry, I don't have rubylog, I'm testing  in SWI-Prolog):

```
synonym(X, Z) :- synonyms(X, L), member(Z, L).

synonym_of(math, mathematics).
synonym_of(mathematics, maths).

synonyms(X, Ss) :- synonyms(X, [], Ss).

synonyms(X, Found, R) :-
    ( synonym_of(X, S) ; synonym_of(S, X) ),
    \+ member(S, Found),
    !, synonyms(S, [S|Found], R).
synonyms(_, Found, Found).
```